# Php web application can't process clearDB mysql service on bluemix

Tags: php, mysql, ibm-cloud, cleardb

I'm trying to deploy a php web application on bluemix. So I have bound a clearDB mysql service to my application. The vcap_service variable are provided to me. but when I use those variable to perform simple sql query, the application page does nothing, while same code is doing well with xamp localhost. 
please help me.

here is the code :

```php
<?php
$servername = "us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net";
$username = "b23807********";
$password = "********";
$dbname = "ad_70723170af1****";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE flybird (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table flybird created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The following error is showing:
 Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/table.php on line 8\n.

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: Sorry sir! but now I've added code .

Comment: Can you please post output of : cf logs **appname** --recent

Comment: Yup! mysqli function was the problem. Now app is doing great . A lot of thanks

Comment: @SahilS can you please accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with the php buildpack, you need to explicitly add the mysqli function in your application.

Create a file called `.bp-config/options.json`.  You can customize the php buildpack extensions, check [this](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/docs/config.md#optionsjson) out for more info.

The contents should contain the following.

```
{
    "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["mysqli"]
}
```

Comment: Yup! mysqli function was the problem. Now app is doing great . A lot of thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should specify mysqli dependency on composer.json config.

`{"require": {
        "ext-mysqli": "*"
     }
   }`

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to explicitly add the mysqli function in your application

You have to enable the library in .bp-config/options.json file. Like the example below

EX:

> {
>       "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["mysqli"]
>      }

If you don't have this file in your aplication just create it, add the extension and push it to your Bluemix app. ([link](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/docs/config.md#optionsjson))

Check this page on developerworks for more information , i think it is the same issue you are having ([link](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/24624/how-to-connect-php-app-to-mysql/?smartspace=bluemix))

Comment: Yup! mysqli function was the problem. Now app is doing great . A lot of thanks